# Repeating Section in Power Apps Does not load data when the user goes back to view the item

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

Im working on a power apps that grants the user the ability to enter data by row and add/remove  rows as needed. Once the user has all the data enter, when they click save, it patches to the SharePoint List in a table format to a rich text column. The user sees this screen to enter data    [When the user gets to screen to add payments info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUNNQ.png) and when it patches to the SP list, it writes like this[patches to sp list item with a table like formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm6sw.png). When the user reviews the item details and  information, it doesn't load the data.[the repeating section loads nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbCA3.png). The goal is to load the same data in the repeating section when the user goes to view the item in canvas apps.

For reference, I've used something similar to this solution to create what I currently have.

https://netwoven.com/sharepoint-custom-development/how-to-create-repeating-section-in-powerapps-and-save-data-to-sharepoint-list/

Note: I've seen solutions where you have a master list then child list with all the details. I want stray away from that solution. Reason being I want to avoid less maintenance and hitting threshold limit on sp list sooner.. However, I am open to any thoughts/ideas. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you are saving the data as an HTML table. Your repeating section cannot parse it back into items.

You should look to save the data as a JSON string to SharePoint as a `Multiple lines of text` and as `Plain text` column type. Then in your app, when you load in the item, you can use the `ParseJSON` function to turn it back into a collection. From this collection, your "repeating section" should be populated etc...

Comment: Not sure if you can then retain the 'table-like' appearance on SharePoint. Perhaps you can use column formatting for that, but I haven't seen that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MatchAll() function to parse the HTML table in your PowerApps. This post can help you out with an example:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Converting-html-table-into-galley/td-p/1926838

Comment: Thank you for sharing that forum. Im trying to fit it to my code. I will post my results.

Comment: Just an update, it actually loads the data in prod without having to reload with MatchAll(). I think it may be buggy in app preview vs prod. Thank you again for your help.